# Best way to wait and redirect to a page in NextJS 13.4.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, clerk

I have the below function in my `OnboardingForm` component at `/onboarding` page.

```
  async function handleFormData(formData: FormData) {
    const result = await createUserFromForm(formData, clerkUserId as string)

    if (result) {
      await setUserDataAtClerk(
        clerkUserId as string,
        formData.get('firstName') as string,
        formData.get('lastName') as string
      )

      redirect('/dashboard')
    } else {
      // Add error handling logic when createUserFromForm doesn't return true
      console.error('User could not be created from form data')
    }
  }
```

Problem:

1. The `setUserDataAtClerk` function updates the user's `isActive` status
   to true. This operation takes some time to complete and propagate to
   the auth service.
2. I have an `authMiddleware` checks for the `isActive` status
   and redirects users who aren't active to `/onboarding`.
3. After calling `setUserDataAtClerk`, my code tries to redirect the user to
   `/dashboard`. However, at that point, the update to `isActive` is not
   propagated, and the middleware still see the old
   status and redirect back to `/onboarding`.

I am using next.js 13.4.4.

What is the best way to solve this challenge?

Comment: You could always set something in the app state (zustand, redux, etc...) or the browser state (localstorage, sessionstorage) to flag this user as having a registration in progress.

Comment: Could you create a loading page between the `onboarding` and `dashboard` pages with the message "We are just activating your account"? Then the page could either poll the server for the `isActive` property and redirect when it is true, or even better, set up a web socket and let the server tell the page when it is active.

Comment: I was just wondering, whether you could use  <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading feed...</p>}> or loading.tsx at all? I tried using  <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading feed...</p>}> wrapper on the OnboardingForm component but it didn't work. I didnt see any loading messages.